# vba value special paste values all sheets same place in specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I am beginner in Excel VBA

I need to to do some specific range to make value in my all worksheet at once

I am using this code but it's taking a long time and not working for all sheet at once

can anyone correct this code

```
Sub Saveasvalue()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Range("B11:F40").Value = Range("B11:F40").Value
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `wsh.Range("B11:F40").Value = wsh.Range("B11:F40").Value`.

Comment: You can get rid of `Application.CutCopyMode = False` as you're not actually using the clipboard here.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you so much for your help It's working fine and fast

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want to do:-

```
Sub Saveasvalue()

    Dim Wsh As Worksheet
    
    For Each Wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not Wsh Is ActiveSheet Then
            Wsh.Range("B11:F40").Value = Range("B11:F40").Value
        End If
    Next Wsh
End Sub
```

Watch out for the `ActiveSheet` in two ways.

1. If you don't specify a sheet the `ActiveSheet` is presumed by default. In your code `Range("B11:F40").Value = Range("B11:F40").Value` copies the range from the `ActiveSheet` to the `ActiveSheet` on each loop. Therefore nothing will ever change.
2. If you loop through all sheets in the workbook one of them will be the `Activesheet`. In the above code that sheet is excluded from the action.

So, the above code loops through all the sheets and copies the specified range from the active sheet to each called sheet. But it will omit that action when the called sheet is the `ActiveSheet`.